# how to get child key without going with parent key or with iteration

Tags: groovy

1.I am having a list which contains multiple Maps that looks like below Map.
    Each map contains many keys I want to get value of "name"

```
    {
       "question":{
          "com.forms.tree":{
             "requiredByDefault":true,
             "questionDetails":{
                "com.forms.Details":{
                   "preferredFormComponent":"TEXT"
                }
             },
             "locale":{
                "language":"en"
             },
             "formField":{
                "name":"CUSTOM_347",
                "tag":"input",
                "url":"Demo"
             }
          }
       },
       "Field":"true"
    },{
   "question":{
      "com.forms.tree":{
         "questionDetails":{
            "com.forms.Details":{
               "preferredFormComponent":"TEXT"
            }
         },
         "locale":{
            "language":"en"
         },
         "formField":{
            "name":"CUSTOM_348",
            "url":"Demo"
         }
      }
   },
   "Field":"true"}
```

I want to get the value of "name" which falls in every Map but don't want to iterate like `question?."com.forms.tree"?.formField?.name`.

```
Is there any other approach in groovy?
```

Comment: Is there only only one value you want to find?  Or is there likely to be 2 `name` elements in the Json?

Comment: I  want values of all "name" which fall under "formField"

Comment: Could there be more than one `formField` in the json?

Answer (score 1):

So given the json:

```
def jsonTxt = '''{
   "question":{
      "com.forms.tree":{
         "requiredByDefault":true,
         "questionDetails":{
            "com.forms.Details":{
               "preferredFormComponent":"TEXT"
            }
         },
         "locale":{
            "name": "test",
            "language":"en"
         },
         "formField":{
            "name":"CUSTOM_347",
            "tag":"input",
            "url":"Demo"
         }
      }
   },
   "Field":"true"
}'''
```

We can parse it with:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonTxt)
```

You want to find the `"formField"` entry in that object, so lets write a recursive finder that will walk through out map of maps looking for the first entry with the given key:

```
static findFirstByKey(Map map, key) {
    map.get(key) ?: map.findResult { k, v -> if(v in Map) findFirstByKey(v, key) }
}
```

And you can then check it works:

```
assert findFirstByKey(json, 'formField')?.name == "CUSTOM_347"
```

Comment: According to my problem jsonTxt is list which contains multiple maps.I think I will get parsing error.

Comment: Multiple maps, or multiple json strings?

Comment: @tim_yates: the input type looks like `List<Map>` which means the entry point of `findFirstByKey` will fail with CCE.

Comment: try: `def names = list.collect { findFirstByKey(it, 'formField')?.name }`

Comment: @anupamakushwah: the solution is to query each element using Tim's function. Assuming `List<Map> input = /*list of maps*/` then `input.collect({findFirstByKey(it, 'formField')})?.name == ['CUSTOM_347']`